# Subtotal on Magento 2.4.5, when coupon is applied

Tags: magento2, cart, subtotal

Subtotal in the cart doesn't change on applying a coupon.
Is it possible for Subtotal to be: (order total - coupon discount) - tax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Subtotal in the cart doesn't changes on applying the coupon code as per the Ecommerce standards.

- The flow is:

Subtotal:

Discount:

Shipping:

Tax:

Grand total:

This is what the complete picture looks like.

The (order total - coupon discount) -tax you are looking for is Grand total.
But if you want, you can use some custom extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Yes only grand total will have a reflection.